# Why are the same characters displayed differently in the same sentence?

Tags: text, internationalization

In some text views on OS X, e.g. in the application QQ, the character →(U+2192) is displayed differently after a Chinese character or Latin character:

[image: right arow]

Also affected are the other arrows, and the box ■(U+25A0):

[image: box]

How is it so?

Comment: QQ is a chat/messenger app. Its text capability are limited. Use double space to try.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the app continues to use the Chinese font for that character, and different fonts will often have slightly different glyphs for such symbols.